# OpenGL, two objects moving independently

Tags: opengl, graphics

I need to move two objects in OpenGL independently.

#### This is vertex positions array:

```c
const float vertexPositions[] = {
    0.25f, 0.25f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.25f, -0.25f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    -0.25f, -0.25f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.75f, 0.45f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.45f, -0.45f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    -0.65f, -0.95f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
};
```

#### This go to a buffer and then there is the following command which draws these triangles:

```c
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3*2);
```

#### Below is part responsible for rotating:

```c
#version 330

layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;
uniform float loopDuration;
uniform float time;

void main()
{
    float timeScale = 3.14159f * 2.0f / loopDuration;

    float currTime = mod(time, loopDuration);
    vec4 totalOffset = vec4(
        cos(currTime * timeScale) * 0.5f,
        sin(currTime * timeScale) * 0.5f,
        0.0f,
        0.0f);

    gl_Position = position + totalOffset;
}
```

Unfortunately it does not work as I expected - instead of moving independently, these triangles seems to be joined together like there were on a plate of glass. What I can do in order to translate and rotate them independently? How can I do it using GPU, not CPU?

Comment: If you want them to act independent you will have to supply them with independent data.  This would be best by passing matrices as uniforms to the fragment shader.  Any basic opengl 3+ tutorial online will cover this.

Comment: @kkuryllo: Having to set uniform values per triangle has the disadvantage that the poster won't be able to draw the triangles with a single draw call anymore.

Comment: You could use additional vertex attributes to specify per triangle (or even per vertex) animation parameters. You can pass them into the vertex shader the same way you pass in the positions, and then use them in the shader code where you apply your animation logic to calculate `gl_Position`.

Comment: Thanks. How can I split gl_Position so that one triangle (first three vertexes) is displayed with offset1 and second triangle is displayed with offset 2? I see only gl_Position which refers to position of all vertexes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'ra doing [this tutorial.](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut) In that case I suggest you to remove the last 12 floats from the `vertexPositions`, so you get the following:

```
const float vertexPositions[] = {
    0.25f, 0.25f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.25f, -0.25f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    -0.25f, -0.25f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
};
```

And change the `glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3*2);` to `glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);`. In your `display()` function, paste after the first calling of `glDrawArrays()` the following:

```
glUniform1f(loopDurationUnf, 2.5f);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
```

This should draw the same triangle with twice the speed.